# Pandas find cell location that matches regex

Tags: python, excel, pandas, regex, dataframe

I'm currently trying to parse [excel files](https://easyupload.io/8nncki) that contain somewhat structured information. The data I am interested in is in a subrange of an excel sheet. Basically the excel contains key-value pairs where the key is usually named in a predictable manner (found with regex). Keys are in the same column and the value pair is on the right side of the key in the excel sheet.

Regex pattern `pattern = r'[Tt]emperature|[Ss]tren|[Cc]omment'`  predictably matches the keys. Therefore if I can find the column where the keys are located and the rows where the keys are present, I am able to find the subrange of interest and parse it further.

Goals:

1. Get list of row indices that match regex (e.g. `[5, 6, 8, 9]`)
2. Find which column contains keys that match regex (e.g. `Unnamed: 3`)

[image: Image of original excel]

When I read in the excel using `df_original = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet)` the dataframe looks like this

```
df_original = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0':['Value', 'Name', np.nan, 'Mark', 'Molly', 'Jack', 'Tom', 'Lena', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Unnamed: 1':['High', 'New York', np.nan, '5000', '5250', '4600', '2500', '4950', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Unnamed: 2':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Unnamed: 3':['Other', 125, 127, np.nan, np.nan, 'Temperature (C)', 'Strength', np.nan, 'Temperature (F)', 'Comment'],
                   'Unnamed: 4':['Other 2', 25, 14.125, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '1500', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Unnamed: 5':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 25, np.nan, np.nan, 77, 'Looks OK'],
                   'Unnamed: 6':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Add water'],
                  })

+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    | Unnamed: 0   | Unnamed: 1   |   Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3      | Unnamed: 4   | Unnamed: 5   | Unnamed: 6   |
|----+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------|
|  0 | Value        | High         |          nan | Other           | Other 2      | nan          | nan          |
|  1 | Name         | New York     |          nan | 125             | 25           | nan          | nan          |
|  2 | nan          | nan          |          nan | 127             | 14.125       | nan          | nan          |
|  3 | Mark         | 5000         |          nan | nan             | nan          | nan          | nan          |
|  4 | Molly        | 5250         |          nan | nan             | nan          | nan          | nan          |
|  5 | Jack         | 4600         |          nan | Temperature (C) | nan          | 25           | nan          |
|  6 | Tom          | 2500         |          nan | Strength        | 1500         | nan          | nan          |
|  7 | Lena         | 4950         |          nan | nan             | nan          | nan          | nan          |
|  8 | nan          | nan          |          nan | Temperature (F) | nan          | 77           | nan          |
|  9 | nan          | nan          |          nan | Comment         | nan          | Looks OK     | Add water    |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

This code finds the rows of interest and solves Goal 1.

```
df = df_original.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
pattern = r'[Tt]emperature|[Ss]tren|[Cc]omment'
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains(pattern, regex=True, na=False) for col in df])
row_range = df.loc[(mask.any(axis=1))].index.to_list()

print(df.loc[(mask.any(axis=1))].index.to_list())

[5, 6, 8, 9]


display(df.loc[row_range])

+----+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    | Unnamed: 0   |   Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 3      |   Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5   | Unnamed: 6   |
|----+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------|
|  5 | Jack         |         4600 | Temperature (C) |          nan | 25           | nan          |
|  6 | Tom          |         2500 | Strength        |         1500 | nan          | nan          |
|  8 | nan          |          nan | Temperature (F) |          nan | 77           | nan          |
|  9 | nan          |          nan | Comment         |          nan | Looks OK     | Add water    |
+----+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What is the easiest way to solve Goal 2? Basically I want to find columns that contain at least one value that matches the regex pattern. The wanted output would be `[Unnamed: 5]`. There may be some easy way to solve goals 1 and 2 at the same time. For example:

```
col_of_interest = 'Unnamed: 3' # <- find this value
col_range = df_original.columns[df_original.columns.to_list().index(col_of_interest): ]
print(col_range)

Index(['Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6'], dtype='object')


target = df_original.loc[row_range, col_range]
display(target)

+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    | Unnamed: 3      |   Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5   | Unnamed: 6   |
|----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------|
|  5 | Temperature (C) |          nan | 25           | nan          |
|  6 | Strength        |         1500 | nan          | nan          |
|  8 | Temperature (F) |          nan | 77           | nan          |
|  9 | Comment         |          nan | Looks OK     | Add water    |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the actual excel file. I think with `janitor.xlsx_cells` an alternative approach is possible

Comment: Also kindly add the expected output dataframe

Comment: Sure, although you can just copy the dataframe output from the code - that is exactly what you get when you read the original excel with Pandas. The wanted output is described in the post.

Comment: Yea, I want to try an alternative approach that I feel may be simpler(subjective opinion of course), hence the request for the excel file as wl as the expected output dataframe

Comment: Added a link to a file in the post. The output described is just a preliminary output that I would then process further, but that part I'm familiar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with [xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); it reads each cell as a single row; this way you are afforded more manipulation freedom; for your use case it can be handy and an alternative:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
```

Read in data

```py
df = jn.xlsx_cells('test.xlsx', include_blank_cells=False)
df.head()
     value internal_value coordinate  row  column data_type  is_date number_format
0    Value          Value         A2    2       1         s    False       General
1     High           High         B2    2       2         s    False       General
2    Other          Other         D2    2       4         s    False       General
3  Other 2        Other 2         E2    2       5         s    False       General
4     Name           Name         A3    3       1         s    False       General
```

Filter for rows that match the pattern:

```py
bools = df.value.str.startswith(('Temperature', 'Strength', 'Comment'), na = False)

vals = df.loc[bools, ['value', 'row', 'column']]

vals
              value  row  column
16  Temperature (C)    7       4
20         Strength    8       4
24  Temperature (F)   10       4
26          Comment   11       4
```

Look for values that are on the same row as `vals`, and are in columns greater than the column in `vals`:

```py
bools = df.column.gt(vals.column.unique().item()) & df.row.between(vals.row.min(), vals.row.max())

result = df.loc[bools, ['value', 'row', 'column']]
result
        value  row  column
17         25    7       6
21       1500    8       5
25         77   10       6
27   Looks OK   11       6
28  Add water   11       7
```

Merge `vals` and `result` to get the final output

```py
(vals
.drop(columns='column')
.rename(columns={'value':'val'})
.merge(result.drop(columns='column'))
) 
               val  row      value
0  Temperature (C)    7         25
1         Strength    8       1500
2  Temperature (F)   10         77
3          Comment   11   Looks OK
4          Comment   11  Add water
```

Comment: This is great but is there some way to replace .startswith() with something that is regex-based instead? Sometimes "Comments" may be "other comments" etc. and pretty much requires the flexibility regex gives to be robust enough.

Comment: Yea, just use your string function to get booleans. In short you can use any pandas function since `df` is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Changed that with `bools = df.value.str.contains(pattern, regex=True, na=False)` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following 2 options:

**Option 1** (assuming no not-`NaN` data below row with "[Tt]emperature (C)" that we *don't* want to include)

```
pattern = r'[Tt]emperature'
idx, col = df_original.stack().str.contains(pattern, regex=True, na=False).idxmax()
res = df_original.loc[idx:, col:].dropna(how='all')

print(res)

        Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
5  Temperature (C)        NaN         25        NaN
6         Strength       1500        NaN        NaN
8  Temperature (F)        NaN         77        NaN
9          Comment        NaN   Looks OK  Add water
```

**Explanation**

- First, we use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to add column names as a level to the index, and get all the data just in one column.
- Now, we can apply [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to find a match for `r'[Tt]emperature'`. We chain [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to "[r]eturn the row label of the maximum value". I.e. this will be the first `True`, so we will get back `(5, 'Unnamed: 3')`, to be stored in `idx` and `col` respectively.
- Now, we know where to start our selection from the `df`, namely at index `5` and column `Unnamed: 3`. If we simply want all the data (to the right, and to bottom) from here on, we can use: `df_original.loc[idx:, col:]` and finally, drop all remaining rows that have only `NaN` values.

---

**Option 2** (potential data below row with "[Tt]emperature (C)" that we don't want to include)

```
pattern = r'[Tt]emperature|[Ss]tren|[Cc]omment'
tmp = df_original.stack().str.contains(pattern, regex=True, na=False)
tmp = tmp[tmp].index

res = df_original.loc[tmp.get_level_values(0), tmp.get_level_values(1)[1]:]
print(res)

        Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
5  Temperature (C)        NaN         25        NaN
6         Strength       1500        NaN        NaN
8  Temperature (F)        NaN         77        NaN
9          Comment        NaN   Looks OK  Add water
```

**Explanantion**

- Basically, the procedure here is the same as with option 1, except that we want to retrieve all the `index values`, rather than just the first one (for "[Tt]emperature (C)"). After `tmp[tmp].index`, we get `tmp` as:

```
MultiIndex([(5, 'Unnamed: 3'),
            (6, 'Unnamed: 3'),
            (8, 'Unnamed: 3'),
            (9, 'Unnamed: 3')],
           )
```

- In the next step, we use these values as coordinates for [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). I.e. for the index selection, we want all values, so we use [`index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html); for the column, we only need the first value (they should all be the same of course: `Unnamed: 3`).